# How to create nested object based on dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to transform some data into a special format. The tricky part is, that it needs to be grouped and nested by dynamic keys. As the raw data is flat.

Here is some simplified example data:

```
const data = [
  {
    category: 'Classic',
    price: 1,
    order: '1233-ABC'
    currency: 'EUR',
  },
  {
    category: 'Classic',
    price: 2,
    order: '1234-ABC'
    currency: 'EUR',
  },
  {
    category: 'Modern',
    price: 3,
    order: '1235-ABC'
    currency: 'USD',
  },
  {
    category: 'Classic',
    price: 4,
    order: '1236-ABC'
    currency: 'EUR',
  },
  {
    category: 'Modern',
    price: 5,
    order: '1237-ABC'
    currency: 'EUR',
  },
  {
    category: 'Classic',
    price: 6,
    order: '1238-ABC'
    currency: 'USD',
  },
  {
    category: 'Modern',
    price: 7,
    order: '1239-ABC'
    currency: 'USD',
  }
];
```

Now I want to define the groupings and the aggregate.

For example:

```
grouping = ['category'];
sum = ['price'];
```

So it should groupBy the `category` key and sum up all `price` key entries.

// Expected Output

```
[{
    category: 'Classic',
    price: 13
}, {
    category: 'Modern',
    price: 15
}]
```

I got this working with reduce.

Here is the code:

```
let groupingsField = ['category'];
let aggregateField = ['price']

let [group, ...rest] = groupingsField
let [sum, ...noone] = aggregateField

const groupedData = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
  acc.push({
    [group]: current[group],
    [sum]: data.filter(item => item[group] === current[group])
    .map(el => el[sum])
    .reduce((total, current) => total + current)
  })

  return acc
}, [])
.reduce((acc, current) => {
  const x = acc.find(item => item[group] === current[group])

  return !x ? acc.concat([current]) : acc
}, [])
```

However, I need the groupings to be dynamic and if more then 1 value is present there, it should create nested `sub` data sets. It should be possible to add multiple groupings.

// Example 2

```
grouping = ['category', 'currency'];
sum = ['price'];
```

// Expected Output

```
[{
    category: 'Classic',
    price: 13,
    sub: [{
        currency: 'EUR',
        price: 7
    }, {
        currency: 'USD',
        price: 6
    }]
}, {
    category: 'Modern',
    price: 15,
    sub: [{
        currency: 'EUR',
        price: 9
    }, {
        currency: 'USD',
        price: 10
    }]
}]
```

Thus, if I would add another key to the grouping

```
grouping = ['category', 'currency', 'something'];
```

It should be three levels deep nestes.

```
{
 category: 'Modern',
 price: 15,
 sub: [{
   currency: 'EUR',
   price: 9,
   sub: [{
     someting: ...
     price: ...
   }]
 }]
}
```

However, I couldn't get my head around this, how to add the nesting dynamically based on the `groupings`. I guess I need some recursion here.

Would love some help on this!

Comment: If you're open to using libs.. Take a look at Lodash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group objects by multiple properties in array then sum up their values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794232/group-objects-by-multiple-properties-in-array-then-sum-up-their-values)

Comment: @PsyGik  Did not found anything usefull in loadash to perform the dynamic n-deep nesting based on a key.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Not exactly. Like I wrote I covered the use-case for only 1 aggregator and one grouping, myself. However I want this to work with multiple groupings that are nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help!
However, after some sleep I came up with my own solution:

```
groups = ['category', 'currency']; // this can be dynamic 
sum = ['price'];

function createGroup (groups, data, sum, childNode = 'sub') {
    let [primaryGroup, ...rest] = groups;

    let groupedData = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
    let chunk = {
        [primaryGroup]: current[primaryGroup],
        [sum]: data.filter(item => item[primaryGroup] === current[primaryGroup])
        .map(el => el[sum])
        .reduce((total, current) => total + current),
       ...(rest.length > 0 ? {[childNode]: createGroup(rest, data)} : {})
    }

    acc.push(chunk)
    return acc
  }, [])
    .reduce((acc, current) => {
        const x = acc.find(item => item[primaryGroup] === current[primaryGroup])
        return !x ? acc.concat([current]) : acc
    }, [])

  return groupedData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... It was indeed a challenge but I think it's working... Maybe not on the most fancy way but I guess it will do.

```
var newArr = [];
var MyObj = {};
var MyObj2 = {};


    for( i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if (data[i].category + '|' + data[i].currency in MyObj) MyObj[data[i].category + '|' + data[i].currency] += data[i].price;
        else MyObj[data[i].category + '|' + data[i].currency] = data[i].price;
    }

    for (var key in MyObj) {
        let keyArr=-1;
        let split_key = key.split("|");


        for( i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
            console.log(newArr[i].category + '/' +split_key[0] + i);
            if (newArr[i].category == split_key[0]) {

                keyArr=i;
                break;
            }
        }

    if (keyArr<0){
        MyObj2['category'] = split_key[0];
        MyObj2['price'] = MyObj[key];
        MyObj2['sub'] = [{currency: split_key[1], price: MyObj[key]}];
        newArr.push(MyObj2);
    }else{
        newArr[keyArr]['price']+=MyObj[key];
        newArr[keyArr]['sub'].push({currency: split_key[1], price: MyObj[key]});
    }

        MyObj2={};

    }
    console.log(newArr);
```