# Group objects by multiple properties including nested properties and sump up their values

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

it's like [Group objects by multiple properties in array then sum up their values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794232/group-objects-by-multiple-properties-in-array-then-sum-up-their-values)
 but with nested elements and more complicated. I've been struggling for hours.

I have an array of products:

a product looks like this :

```
{
    "commissioningDate": "2019-09-27",
    "_product": {
        "_id": "aaa",
        "name": "Installation"
    },
    "zones": [
        {
            "_zone": {
                "_id": "KK",
                "name": "Zone kk"
            },
            "category": "category1",
            "zone_quantity": 6
        }
    ],
    "product_quantity": 3
}
```

**Expected behavior**

I made this [gist](https://gist.github.com/thorizer/a6abb470dbdada35bf879266d94883e7) because the example is too long.

**Problem**

So I have an array of products.

1) products in this array are considered duplicates only if both their `commissioningDate` and `_product._id` are the same

2) if many products gets merged into a single product:

- we need a to sum-up the `product_quantity`
- we need to merge the zone array inside the product if possible otherwise add it to the array

3) zones of a merged product in this array are considered duplicates only if both their `_zone._id` and `category` are the same

4) if many zones gets merged into a single zone we need a to sum-up the `zone_quantity`

Answer (score 2):

Assume your single product zones always has length 1.

```js
const sample = [
    {
        "commissioningDate": "2019-09-27",
        "_product": {
            "_id": "aaa",
            "name": "Installation"
        },
        "zones": [
            {
                "_zone": {
                    "_id": "KK",
                    "name": "Zone kk"
                },
                "category": "category1",
                "zone_quantity": 6
            }
        ],
        "product_quantity": 3
    },
    {
        "commissioningDate": "2019-09-27",
        "_product": {
            "_id": "aaa",
            "name": "Installation"
        },
        "zones": [
            {
                "_zone": {
                    "_id": "KK",
                    "name": "Zone kk"
                },
                "category": "category2",
                "zone_quantity": 3
            }
        ],
        "product_quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "commissioningDate": "2019-09-27",
        "_product": {
            "_id": "aaa",
            "name": "Installation"
        },
        "zones": [
            {
                "_zone": {
                    "_id": "KK",
                    "name": "Zone kk"
                },
                "category": "category2",
                "zone_quantity": 4
            }
        ],
        "product_quantity": 5
    },
    {
        "commissioningDate": "2019-09-27",
        "_product": {
            "_id": "aaa",
            "name": "Installation"
        },
        "zones": [
            {
                "_zone": {
                    "_id": "CC",
                    "name": "Zone cc"
                },
                "category": "category2",
                "zone_quantity": 6
            }
        ],
        "product_quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "commissioningDate": "2019-09-27",
        "_product": {
            "_id": "bbbb",
            "name": "Installation"
        },
        "zones": [
            {
                "_zone": {
                    "_id": "CC",
                    "name": "Zone cc"
                },
                "category": "category2",
                "zone_quantity": 8
            }
        ],
        "product_quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "commissioningDate": "2019-09-26",
        "_product": {
            "_id": "bbbb",
            "name": "Installation"
        },
        "zones": [
            {
                "_zone": {
                    "_id": "CC",
                    "name": "Zone cc"
                },
                "category": "category2",
                "zone_quantity": 8
            }
        ],
        "product_quantity": 2
    }
]

//reduce initialze value is an empty object
const res = sample.reduce((group, item) => {
  //for each item, generate a key k by combining item commissioningDate and item _product._id seperated //by a comma 
  const k = `${item.commissioningDate},${item._product._id}`;
  
  //check if this key k exists in our object group(which is an empty object when we check the first //item)
  //if it is not in the object, we save the key k and its value which is current item into the object //group
  if(!group[k]) group[k] = Object.assign({}, item);
  
  //if it is in the object already 
  else{
  
  //we sum up current item quantity to the group of this item
    group[k].product_quantity+=item.product_quantity;
    
    //find index of zone in current group zones has the same zone id and category as item's
    for(const itemZone of item.zones){
      const zoneIdx = group[k].zones.findIndex(zone => zone._zone._id === itemZone._zone._id && zone.category === itemZone.category)

      //index is -1, it's not in group zones, we push the zone to group zones array
      if(zoneIdx === -1){
        group[k].zones.push(itemZone)
      }
      //in group zones, we sum up zone_quantity
      else{
        group[k].zones[zoneIdx].zone_quantity += itemZone.zone_quantity
      }
    }
    
  }
  //update current group
  return group
}, {})

//recall keys are our custom identifier for different groups of items, values are actually groups of //items, so we only need to get values from group object
console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Comment: thank you, i'm gonna test this and try to understand it. but most of the time my single product zones has length more than 1

Comment: @AmineDa. can you add example of that as well ?

Comment: also i'm using es5

Comment: @AmineDa. you can just go to babel.io and paste es6 code and you will get a es5 version, that's not a issue.

Comment: @CodeManiac sure will do that

Comment: Just add some comments step by step to the code snippet, hope it helps. If you are using es5, it will be similar, you can use object.assign instead of spread, and arrow function can easily be replaced by function().

Comment: If you have zone length more than 1, it will be similar, just iterate items zones and compare to current group zones.

Comment: @CodeManiac gist updated! it's the same principle . merge the zone who has the same id and category if their product has the same id and date.

Comment: @CodeManiac most of the time when we merge products we just concat  zones arrays of the merged products unless they have the same zone.id and category

Comment: @Colin the only thing you need to change is `findIndex` and `group[k].zones.push(item.zones[0])` this part, in case there are multiple you need to use `filter` and then check length for whether it found or not

Comment: @CodeManiac can you plz update the code it's 3am in here. I need it for tomorrow. I've been struggling all night

Comment: @AmineDa. colin has already updated code, you can check answer. since it already a good answer i don't wanna post other one

Comment: @CodeManiac I tried babel.io but the conversion has some issues . still some spread  operators... and iterators

Comment: @CodeManiac error inside babel conversion : typeError("Invalid attempt to iterate non-iterable instance.\nIn order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.")

Comment: @CodeManiac It won't be multiple since zones in group has unique zone id and category, if there are multiple they are already grouped

Comment: @AmineDa. you can use object.assign to copy object, no need to use spread. I think object.assign should be okay with es5

Comment: @Colin i'm still trying ,   = {...item}; would be  object.assign(item, {})  ?

Comment: @AmineDa. I think it's Object.assign({}, item)