# Merge javascript object using keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need solution of merging objects using keys.

```js
var data = [
  { FromSize: 54, ToSize: 51, ClearityName: 'IF', Price: 56 },
  { FromSize: 54, ToSize: 51, ClearityName: 'VS', Price: 96 },
  { FromSize: 54, ToSize: 51, ClearityName: 'VSS', Price: 26 },
  { FromSize: 40, ToSize: 30, ClearityName: 'PF', Price: 36 },
  { FromSize: 40, ToSize: 30, ClearityName: 'IF', Price: 86 }
];
```

**Output will be like given bellow**

```js
[
  { FromSize: 54, ToSize: 51, IF: 56, VS: 96, VSS: 26 },
  { FromSize: 40, ToSize: 30, PF: 36, IF: 86 }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried by using of grouping but did not worked @Pilpo

Comment: Please show what you did then and in what way it failed, thank you.

Comment: My suggestion is to create an object, then iterate over the data, create a key made from a combination of `FromSize` and `ToSize` (e.g. joined by some character) for each record, create an entry in the object  for that key if it doesn't yet exist, set the property on the entry based on `ClearityName` and `Price`, and at the end output the `Object.values` of your object.

Comment: i have tried using with the help this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794232/group-objects-by-multiple-properties-in-array-then-sum-up-their-values)
i am not star of javascript. i have not much experice in javascript. thank you @CherryDT

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is to create an object, then iterate over the data, create a key made from a combination of `FromSize` and `ToSize` (e.g. joined by some character) for each record, create an entry in the object for that key if it doesn't yet exist, set the property on the entry based on `ClearityName` and `Price`, and at the end output the `Object.values` of your object.

---

**Let's look at it step by step:**

First, let's create an object which will temporarily hold our results as mapping from some key to some value:

```js
const groupedData = {}
```

Then, let's iterate over our data using `for of`:

```js
for (const record of data) {
  /* ... */
}
```

We could now access the values using `record.FromSize`, etc. but the following code will be shorter if we **destructure** the properties at this point already, because we can take advantage of property shorthands (e.g. we can write `{ FromSize }` instead of `{ FromSize: record.FromSize }`):

```js
for (const { FromSize, ToSize, ClearityName, Price } of data) {
  /* ... */
}
```

For each record, we'll first build a key string from `FromSize` and `ToSize` so we can group by it. Since it's two values, we need to join them somehow. Since both are numbers, it's safe to just join them by a character like a comma so that `FromSize: 54, ToSize: 51` will give you `54,51`:

```
const key = `${FromSize},${ToSize}`
```

Then if we create an entry in our grouped data object for the current key if it doesn't exist already. This entry will contain just the base properties of `FromSize` and `ToSize` because the others will be created individually afterwards:

```
groupedData[key] ??= { FromSize, ToSize }
```

The `??=` operator is relatively new in JavaScript. `x ??= y` means the same as `x = x ?? y`, with `??` being the **nullish coalescing operator** which evaluates to its right-hand-side argument if the left-hand-side argument is `null` or `undefined`, otherwise it will evaluate to the left-hand-side argument. Essentially, `x ??= y` allows us to set `x` to `y` if it wasn't already set to something else before (more or less). If this gives you a syntax error, try the more verbose way of `if (!groupedData[key]) groupedData[key] = { FromSize, ToSize }` instead.

Now that we have ensured that `groupedData[key]` exists and has at least `FromSize` and `ToSize` set, we can set the new property that we need based on the `ClearityName`, with a value of `Price`:

```js
groupedData[key][ClearityName] = Price
```

At this point, after our loop is completed, we have `groupedData` as object with keys like `54,51` and values like `{ FromSize: 54, ToSize: 51, IF: 56, VS: 96, VSS: 26 }`, but you want an array of those values and are no longer interested in the keys at that point. You can get that using `Object.values`:

```js
const output = Object.values(groupedData)
```

---

**Final result:**

```js
function getGroupedArray (data) {
  const groupedData = {}
  
  for (const { FromSize, ToSize, ClearityName, Price } of data) {
    const key = `${FromSize},${ToSize}`
    groupedData[key] ??= { FromSize, ToSize }
    groupedData[key][ClearityName] = Price
  }
  
  return Object.values(groupedData)
}

// Let's test it:

const data = [
  { FromSize: 54, ToSize: 51, ClearityName: 'IF', Price: 56 },
  { FromSize: 54, ToSize: 51, ClearityName: 'VS', Price: 96 },
  { FromSize: 54, ToSize: 51, ClearityName: 'VSS', Price: 26 },
  { FromSize: 40, ToSize: 30, ClearityName: 'PF', Price: 36 },
  { FromSize: 40, ToSize: 30, ClearityName: 'IF', Price: 86 },
]

console.log(getGroupedArray(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Click "Run code snippet" above to see it in action!

*(Note: You can ignore the `.as-console-wrapper` stuff here, that's just so that Stack Overflow will display the output in a nicer way.)*

You can find more information about each of the functions used here by googling their names. If you are stuck understanding a certain piece of code I used here, just ask!