# Combining multiple arrays (with similar id) into an object in js

Tags: javascript

I have an array in this format:

```
let array = [
  { text: "Green marbles", number: 10, n: 1 },
  { text: "Pink marbles", number: 5, n: 1 },
  { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 2, n: 1 },
  { text: "Green marbles", number: 10, n: 2 },
  { text: "Pink marbles", number: 5, n: 2 },
  { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 2, n: 2 }
]
```

The desired result would be:

```
let formatArray = [
  { n: 1, "Green marbles": 10, "Pink marbles": 5, "Yellow marbles": 2 },
  { n: 2, "Green marbles": 10, "Pink marbles": 5, "Yellow marbles": 2 }
];
```

The number is not constant (just for this example it is)I tried doing this:

```
let formatArray = [];

array.forEach(el=> {
  Object.keys(el).forEach(eel=> {
   formatArray.push(/*…???*/)
  })
})
```

Stuck here, but I think that this would be the idea

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group objects by multiple properties in array then sum up their values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794232/group-objects-by-multiple-properties-in-array-then-sum-up-their-values)

Comment: It does not, since i want each marble color to be in the same object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `reduce` method to return a new array with the values you want.

```js
let array = [
  { text: "Green marbles", number: 10, n: 1 },
  { text: "Pink marbles", number: 5, n: 1 },
  { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 2, n: 1 },
  { text: "Green marbles", number: 10, n: 2 },
  { text: "Pink marbles", number: 5, n: 2 },
  { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 2, n: 2 }
]

const formatArray = array.reduce((accum, iter) => {
  const {n, text, number} = iter
  if (accum[n-1] === undefined) accum[n-1] = {}
  accum[n-1].n = n
  accum[n-1][text] = number
  return accum
}, [])

console.log(formatArray)
```

I am using the `[]` to set the key to be one of the iterator's values.  I am also letting the `n` value set which object the iterator needs to be added to.

Comment: When i do it, I only get 2 objects in the array, the n values can go to 20, 100, …. In my case i showed only 2 n values

Comment: Is there a way of having n number of objects?

Comment: I am confused, because the output of my code snippet is the desired result you asked for.  Can you edit your question, or elaborate here what you would desire?  If you add more `n` values to my solution, you should get more objects...

Comment: My answer is assuming the `n` values increment by one, and that the total number of objects should be the highest `n` value.  Happy to update my answer to include many more `n` if my assumption is correct.

Comment: @JoshuaBitton I guess we got our wires crossed.  It seems like you hadn't gotten my edit when you tried to use my solution.  Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled as a 'group by' on `n` accumulating the various marble colors into each grouped object.

```js
let array = [{ text: "Green marbles", number: 6, n: 1 }, { text: "Pink marbles", number: 3, n: 1 }, { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 2, n: 1 }, { text: "Green marbles", number: 12, n: 2 }, { text: "Pink marbles", number: 7, n: 2 }, { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 1, n: 2 }];

const temp = {};
for (const { n, number, text } of array) {
  if (temp[n] === undefined) temp[n] = { n, "Green marbles": 0, "Pink marbles": 0, "Yellow marbles": 0 };

  temp[n][text] += number;
}

const result = Object.values(temp);

console.log(result);
```

If you're not sure of the 'marble colors' properties ahead of time you can make it more dynamic

```js
let array = [{ text: "Green marbles", number: 6, n: 1 }, { text: "Pink marbles", number: 3, n: 1 }, { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 2, n: 1 }, { text: "Green marbles", number: 12, n: 2 }, { text: "Pink marbles", number: 7, n: 2 }, { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 1, n: 2 }];

const temp = {};
for (const { n, number, text } of array) {
  if (temp[n] === undefined) temp[n] = { n };

  temp[n][text] = (temp[n][text] ?? 0) + number;
}

const result = Object.values(temp);

console.log(result);
```

or as a `reduce()` call

```js
let array = [{ text: "Green marbles", number: 6, n: 1 }, { text: "Pink marbles", number: 3, n: 1 }, { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 2, n: 1 }, { text: "Green marbles", number: 12, n: 2 }, { text: "Pink marbles", number: 7, n: 2 }, { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 1, n: 2 }];

const result = Object.values(
  array.reduce((a, { n, number, text }) =>
    (a[n] = { ...(a[n] ??= { n }), [text]: (a[n][text] ?? 0) + number }, a), {}));

console.log(result);
```

But it seems that your array might actually be ordered with every *x* rows describing a new `n`.

If this is the case you can use a simple `for` loop and check if the index is evenly divisible by *x*.

```js
let array = [{ text: "Green marbles", number: 6, n: 1 }, { text: "Pink marbles", number: 3, n: 1 }, { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 2, n: 1 }, { text: "Green marbles", number: 12, n: 2 }, { text: "Pink marbles", number: 7, n: 2 }, { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 1, n: 2 }];

let
  result = [],
  color_count = 3,
  prev;
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const { n, number, text } = array[i];

  if (i % color_count === 0) {
    prev = { n };
    result.push(prev);
  }

  prev[text] = number;
}

console.log(result);
```

Or, if they are indeed in order, but you don't know how many per `n` you can track the current object, and if the `n` doesn't match on any iteration push a new obect to the result.

```js
let array = [{ text: "Green marbles", number: 6, n: 1 }, { text: "Pink marbles", number: 3, n: 1 }, { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 2, n: 1 }, { text: "Green marbles", number: 12, n: 2 }, { text: "Pink marbles", number: 7, n: 2 }, { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 1, n: 2 }];

let result = [], prev;
for (const { n, number, text } of array) {

  if (!prev || prev.n !== n) {
    prev = { n };
    result.push(prev);
  }

  prev[text] = number;
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You can easily achieve the result efficiently using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as:

```
array.reduce((map, curr) => map.set(curr.n, { ...(map.get(curr.n) ?? {}), [curr.text]: curr.number }), new Map())
```

```js
let array = [
  { text: "Green marbles", number: 10, n: 1 },
  { text: "Pink marbles", number: 5, n: 1 },
  { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 2, n: 1 },
  { text: "Green marbles", number: 10, n: 2 },
  { text: "Pink marbles", number: 5, n: 2 },
  { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 2, n: 2 },
];

let collection = array.reduce((map, curr) => map.set(curr.n, { ...(map.get(curr.n) ?? {}), [curr.text]: curr.number }), new Map());

const formatArray = [...collection.values()];
console.log(formatArray);
```

**2)** One-liner solution

```
let formatArray = [ ...array.reduce((map, curr) => map.set(curr.n, { ...(map.get(curr.n) ?? {}), [curr.text]: curr.number }), new Map()).values()];
```

```js
let array = [
  { text: "Green marbles", number: 10, n: 1 },
  { text: "Pink marbles", number: 5, n: 1 },
  { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 2, n: 1 },
  { text: "Green marbles", number: 10, n: 2 },
  { text: "Pink marbles", number: 5, n: 2 },
  { text: "Yellow marbles", number: 2, n: 2 },
];

let formatArray = [ ...array.reduce((map, curr) => map.set(curr.n, { ...(map.get(curr.n) ?? {}), [curr.text]: curr.number }), new Map()).values()];

console.log(formatArray);
```