# Php group array of object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I mentioned my php array object following below,

```
$arr ='[
{
    "id": 4667,
    "brand": "Michelin",
    "model": "Pilot Super Sport",
    "width": "255",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19",
},
{
    "id": 4668,
    "brand": "Michelin",
    "model": "Pilot Super Sport",
    "width": "275",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19",
},
{
    "id": 4669,
    "brand": "Pirelli",
    "model": "Zero",
    "width": "255",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19",
},
{
    "id": 4670,
    "brand": "Pirelli",
    "model": "Zero",
    "width": "275",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19",
}]';
```

I want to split array into front and rear separate like following below based on width.

```
$front = '[
{
    "id": 4667,
    "brand": "Michelin",
    "model": "Pilot Super Sport",
    "width": "255",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19",
},
{
    "id": 4669,
    "brand": "Pirelli",
    "model": "Zero",
    "width": "255",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19",
}]';

$rear = '[
{
    "id": 4668,
    "brand": "Michelin",
    "model": "Pilot Super Sport",
    "width": "275",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19",
},
{
    "id": 4670,
    "brand": "Pirelli",
    "model": "Zero",
    "width": "275",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19",
}]';
```

It's there any way php can compare each object width value and group them which is match. please advise. thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Based on what are they classified as front or rear?

Comment: Please, show us your actual code. Thank you.

Comment: Note: the given code is not a valid PHP code.

Comment: Hello Syscall please wait i will update my php code

Comment: Hello Geert, Based on Tire width we can split front & rear

Comment: code is not valid it should be like:
$arr='[{
    "id": 4667,
    "brand": "Michelin",
    "model": "Pilot Super Sport",
    "width": "255",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19"
}, {
    "id": 4668,
    "brand": "Michelin",
    "model": "Pilot Super Sport",
    "width": "275",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19"
}, {
    "id": 4669,
    "brand": "Pirelli",
    "model": "Zero",
    "width": "255",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19"
}, {
    "id": 4670,
    "brand": "Pirelli",
    "model": "Zero",
    "width": "275",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19"
}]';

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use below code:

```
$arr='[{
    "id": 4667,
    "brand": "Michelin",
    "model": "Pilot Super Sport",
    "width": "255",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19"
}, {
    "id": 4668,
    "brand": "Michelin",
    "model": "Pilot Super Sport",
    "width": "275",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19"
}, {
    "id": 4669,
    "brand": "Pirelli",
    "model": "Zero",
    "width": "255",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19"
}, {
    "id": 4670,
    "brand": "Pirelli",
    "model": "Zero",
    "width": "275",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19"
}]'; 
$front=[];
$rear=[];
foreach(json_decode($arr,true) as $key=>$val)
{
  
  if($val['width']==255)
  {
    $front[]=$val;
  }
  else{
    $rear[]=$val;
  }
}  

$front=json_encode($front);
$rear=json_encode($rear);
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay i need to split array based on width

Comment: You can pass argument based on width in array_chunk.

Comment: if total elemets are 10 then you need 5 in front and 5 in rear, right?

Comment: Sometime we will get available product 3 front tires & 5 rear tires, in database return all 8 elements in single array i need to display product front and rear separate, we can identify front and rear using width only

Comment: I have updated code please check. you can put condition for front as per requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but i am sorry thats not working for me. in following link they did that using javascript i need to do something like that in php. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794232/group-objects-by-multiple-properties-in-array-then-sum-up-their-values

Comment: Did you correct your JSON? it should be like:$arr='[{
    "id": 4667,
    "brand": "Michelin",
    "model": "Pilot Super Sport",
    "width": "255",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19"
}, {
    "id": 4668,
    "brand": "Michelin",
    "model": "Pilot Super Sport",
    "width": "275",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19"
}, {
    "id": 4669,
    "brand": "Pirelli",
    "model": "Zero",
    "width": "255",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19"
}, {
    "id": 4670,
    "brand": "Pirelli",
    "model": "Zero",
    "width": "275",
    "height": "35",
    "rim": "19"
}]';

Comment: For front what are the width we need to consider or its fixed 255?

Comment: Yes i update corrections, thank you so much.. & 255 is not fixed value it will change based on tire modal but every JSON will have only two different width size

Comment: Yeah so you need to make dynamic check here  if($val['width']==255) as per your requirement

Comment: Sorry for late reply, PHP Hupp Technologies.. Yeah ive got spark after look into your code and finally i get what i need.. please check if there's any way to make that code optimize please advise

Comment: $all = [];
   $front = [];
   $rear = [];

   for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++){
    array_push($all, $arr[$i]->width);
   }

   $filter = array_unique($all);
   $max = max($filter);
   $min = min($filter);
   
   for($j=0; $j<count($arr); $j++){
    if($arr[$j]->width == $max){
     array_push($rear, $arr[$j]);
    } else if($arr[$j]->width == $min){
     array_push($front, $arr[$j]);
    } else {
     echo 'Not Match';
    }
   }

   echo "<script>console.log(".json_encode($front).")</script>";
   echo "<script>console.log(".json_encode($rear).")</script>";

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me but need to simplify

```
 $all = []; $front = []; $rear = [];

        for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++){
            array_push($all, $arr[$i]->width);
        }

        $filter = array_unique($all);
        $max = max($filter);
        $min = min($filter);
        
        for($j=0; $j<count($arr); $j++){
            if($arr[$j]->width == $max){
                array_push($rear, $arr[$j]);
            } else if($arr[$j]->width == $min){
                array_push($front, $arr[$j]);
            } else {
                echo 'Not Match';
            }
        }

        echo "<script>console.log(".json_encode($front).")</script>";
        echo "<script>console.log(".json_encode($rear).")</script>";
```